# Rock-solid jQuery plugin template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, plugins

I got rejected from CodeCanyon just a few minutes ago and I'm kinda disappointed, because I used this template from CSS-Tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-plugin-template/

I'm not a JS ninja and I thought this was a solid template, but here are some problems with it:

- It's using two namespaces
- Does not follow conventional patterns. Example:

  `var zoomWizard = function(el, options) { 
      var base = this; 
      base.$el = $(el);
      base.el = el;
  };`

As a "correct" approach to the above snippet I was given "this.el = el" and etc, which breaks the whole purpose of base.el! The idea of 'base' is to reference the 'this' object from other functions without scope issues. At least as far as I understand it.

But wait, there's more:
- It is bad practice to define methods inside a constructor function; it wastes CPU and memory resources. Example:

```
base.functionName = function() {
    ....
}
```

- The default options should be defined on $.fn.zoomWizard instead of $.zoomWizard

I tried googling for a solid jquery plugin template that doesn't suggest using the above practices, but couldn't find anything "high profile" as the one at css-tricks. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question (i hope it does). I use this template for creating jquery plugins:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend(
{
    //plugin name here
    functionName: function(options) 
    {

        //Settings list and the default values
        var defaults = 
        {
           defaultvar1: "value",
           defaultvar2: "value"
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() 
        {
            var o =options;
            var obj = $(this);             
            //do stuff here
            }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

AFAIK two namespaces is ok if it's two different functions. If it's not then you're "polluting" the namespace list and should add modifiers as a parameter aka `.zoom("in", 300);` and `.zoom("out", 300);` and not `.zoomIn(300)` and `.zoomOut(300)`.

Comment: Where would you define a method inside this tempalte?

Comment: The defaults as a private object inside the plugin-function is not best practice, because how would you make them configurable from outside this way?

Comment: I call the plugin like this: $(target).pluginName({ option1 : val1 ... }) and is working fine.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with method, but if you mean something like $("#id").zoom() then write the code you need in the section where it says //do stuff here and call it with .functionName().

Comment: It's optional to make them private. Some options are not always to be tampered with :) just move them out if you want people to access them.

Comment: No, didn't mean quite that. I meant functions that are within the plugin, just to make the code more readable (and efficient). For example, a function that wraps an element with HTML, setup styles, etc etc. Stuff like that. Where would you put a function like this?

Comment: I think i know what you mean... functions that aren't local to a namespace, but can be used by several namespaces? I'm not sure really, i havent' had the need for it myself yet. In theory only the plugin is private, it should still be able to call outside functions? In this case create a new JS document and call functions from the plugin? Having them return something is probably the easiest way to do it - but i'm no expert in that field.

If it's ok for them to be local then just add the functions to the //do stuff here. That should be completely valid :)